# Vertically aligned grid with jqgrid plugin

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am trying to build a grid with headers in column1 and the values(data) in the subsequent column. The grid will look like this.
[sample grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEnoH.png)

I went through multiple articles, documentations and examples on jqgrid and the closest I could get is the pivot grid which has this kind of layout but it does not serve my requirement. Is there any way to get the grid layout like above using the jqgrid?

Comment: Are you the one who creates/reads the data from the database?  If that's the case, you could transpose also data and then regenerate ColModel in JS

Answer (score 0):

Try the new in version 5.7 transpose module. It is available only in commercial Guriddo jqGrid

[Documentation](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/transposed/)

[Demo](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/loading_data/transposed/index.html)